# CFQを使わずにlinux上で低負荷でファイルのコピーを行う方法

Tags: linux

例えば運用中で負荷が一定以上あるサーバーにおいて、数ギガバイト程度大きさのファイルをコピーする場合に低負荷でファイルのコピーを行う方法はあるのでしょうか？

尚、I/OスケジューラーはCFQ以外とします。

Comment: 同じような質問がありました。
[How can I reduce resource usage when copying a large file?](http://serverfault.com/questions/258321/how-can-i-reduce-resource-usage-when-copying-a-large-file)

Comment: I/OスケジューラーにCFQ使っている場合はionice使えば特定の条件下である程度負荷をコントロールできるんですが、そうでない場合のなにかいい手段とかないかなー、というのが質問の意図となります。

Answer (score 8):

@heliac2001 さんのリンク内にもありますが、`rsync`に帯域制限を設ける方法はどうでしょうか。IOスケジューラが`noop`でも効果を確認できました。

例えば500kbpsでコピーする場合

```
rsync --bwlimit=500 fromfile tofile
```

などと出来ます。

処理時間がかかるようにはなるものの、`iostat -x 1`で確認すると

- %system
- %iowait
- %util

等が抑えられていることを確認できました。

Comment: そういえばrsyncって自前でsleepして帯域制御していましたね。localでも有効だとは気づきませんでした。補足ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 4):

すでに回答が出ていますが別の方法として、scp や pv にも帯域制限のオプションがあります。

```
scp -l 500 fromfile tofile
pv -L 500k fromfile > tofile
```

また、より汎用的な方法として、コピープロセスを SIGSTOPとSIGCONTで制御すれば低負荷のコピーが可能です。

```
cp hoge foo &
PID=$!
while kill -0 $PID ; do
  kill -s 19 $PID
  sleep 5
  kill -s 18 $PID
  sleep 10
done
```